# VueJS instance is being called even if the element is not on the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I face an issue where all my VueJS instances are being called even if the element is not on the page.

I have a mixin declared like this.

```
var mixin = {
  methods: {
    listEvents(parameters) { 
      return axios.get('/api/v1/events', {params: parameters})
    },
    listLocations(parameters) { 
      return axios.get('/api/v1/locations', {params: parameters})
    },
  }
}
```

And multiple instances, that use this mixing. If you ask why multiple instances, it is because I use VuejS in multiple pages. For example, I have a page that is listing **events** and a page that is listing **locations**. So all my methods are in the mixin, and then the instance that is made for the page is called because the page contains the *element* specified in the instance (for example : id="locations" and el: "#locations")

Example of one instance :

```
// Vue
new Vue({
  el: '#locations',
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  mixins: [mixin],
  data: {
    locations: [],
    loading: true,
    error: false,
    page: 1,
    perPage: 20,
  },
  mounted: function () {
    console.log("VUEJS 'locations' has been mounted")
    this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
...
...
```

But, whatever the page I am on, all the instances are called... I can see all the API calls, the leaflet maps are initiated but there is no container, ... it is a mess.

Am I missing something or misunderstanding totally ?

EDIT : I may add that all instances are in `app.js` and this `app.js` is included in all pages.

Comment: So you're instantiating Vue on every page and you're asking why Vue is getting instantiated on every page? When you call `new Vue();`, you're instantiating Vue.

Comment: I do not think that is what OP is asking. They call `init` in `mounted`. To the best of my knowledge, `mounted` should not be called if the root HTML element does not exist on the page.

Comment: @KamilJarosz : I am pretty sure that I missed something, fine, but `element` is here to say to VueJs : you need to be used or not. No ? I mean, the `init()` method that I used is in the `mounted` part...

Comment: You understand it correctly, but the Vue will be created regardless of whether the element exists or not. It just won't be mounted to a null (non existing) element.

Comment: @Bert : Hum... This is a sad news, I mean.. I thought it was the aim of `element`. I saw your solution, thanks a lot. But, I find this a bit "ugly" because I wanted pure VuejS code only. Am I the only to use VueJS on multiple pages ?

Comment: No, I think people either don't load the script on pages where it's not necessary, or they don't have a problem using javascript. Unfortunately I don't see another way around it.

Comment: @Bert : Well, to be honest, I just replaced all my jQuery code full of DOM selectors by this VueJS code that I found more beautiful and powerful.

Comment: Vue is definitely nicer to work with (IMO) than jQuery, so I think that's a good choice. There is no easy way to back out of creating an object however. The object passed to `new Vue` is just an initialization object. A Vue object is going to be created no matter what; that is just how javascript works.

Comment: @Elwyn, If your app has multiple pages, why not just split your Vue instances for those particular pages and use the appropriate scripts for each instead of downloading one-size-fits all `app.js` for every page? It sounds like you're trying to run a multi-page app with single-page scripts.

Comment: @KamilJarosz : That is exactly what I am doing yes, and I was thinking about split it, now that I understand... But what am I doing with the `mixing` part ? I like the idea of **services functions** in the `mixin`. Oh, and I also reuse components.. That I also declared in the `app.js`.

Comment: @Bert : Ok thanks a lot

Comment: @Elwyn, You can still use a mixin. You only add the mixin when you are instantiating Vue. So when you split up your code, and you're on one of the pages that's instantiating Vue, you just give your Vue instance the mixin to extend its functionality.

Comment: @KamilJarosz : Ok thanks a lot ! For example, all the mixin code in a file `app.config.js` always included in all pages, and for each page, I only include the `app.js` with the Vue instance that interests me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have some script that is loaded on every page, instantiating new Vue objects, regardless of whether or not the elements those Vues attach to are rendered.

Vue will create instances even if the element you are instantiating it on does not exist.

That being the case, you could simply check to see if the elements exist before you create the Vue.

```
const locations = document.querySelector("#locations")
if (locations) {
  new Vue({
    el: "#locations",
    ...
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. But I do not like the term workaround because it means that what I want to achieve with VueJS is not correct..